# C - Removing int messes up queue

Tags: c, integer, queue

I have a struct containing an array of integers and an int ("rear") showing the end of the queue. I have some functions, e.g. add(), remove() and print().

The remove() function should move all items forward (effectively deleting the arr[0], replacing it by arr[1], but it does not work.

if my array looks like 111,222,333,444 and I call remove(), the result looks something like 112,223,334, etc.

So far I was able to solve all the often really frustrating problems, mainly related to Java, but this C problem I just do not understand at all. I hope for some input from you. Thanks.

The relevant part of code:

```
void remove( struct queue *q )
{
    int i;
    system ("cls");

    if ( q->rear >  0)
    {
        printf("\n\n%d has been removed\n\n", q->rank[0]);
        q->rear--;
        for ( i = 0; i < q->rear; i++)
        {
            q->rank[i] = q ->rank[i]++;
            printf(rank[i])
        }
        q->rank[(q->rear +1)] = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nThe queue is empty\n\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

`q->rank[i] = q ->rank[i]++;`

should be

`q->rank[i] = q ->rank[i+1];`

otherwise you're incrementing i twice in the loop.

Comment: It works and the explanation is clear, thank you. I still don't understand though how can parts of an int get mixed up with parts of other integers, could you explain that? Even if I see now what the problem was, I still can't explain the behavior it produced.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean - your example output looks like you're dealing with chars, not ints, and that the remove() function is doing what it's supposed to do - removing the first char and shift all the others to the left, including the commas.

Comment: OK got it now. It doesn't increment i, it increments the value stored in arr[i]...